# Stopping at the first occurrence of a pattern and searchable the next line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

```
function fun() {
    var temp = document.getElementById('DIV2').innerHTML;
    var str = temp;
    var res = str.replace(/(\s(\S*m)\s)/gi, ' <span class="red">$1</span> '); // 0.5 -- 1m -- etc 
    var res2 = res.replace(/\s(\S*metre)\s/gi, '<span class="red">$1</span> '); // 1meter 2meter
    var res3 = res.replace(/\s(\S\s*metre)\s/gi, '<span class="red">$1</span> '); // 1 meter 2 meter
    document.body.innerHTML = res3;
}
```

```
<body>
    <div id="text">
    The Basic High Speed HDMI 0.5m Cables with Ethernet are 0.5m suitable for use with HDMI.
    Home Theater, 1m Games Consoles (including Nintendo Wii U), 1m Blu-rays, Cable or Satelite 1m boxes and Projectors. 
    HDMI Cables provides the most reliable digital signal transfer and the purest picture. 
    </div>
</html>
```

The above code matches `"0.5m, 1m, 1 metre"` etc. in a string but it searches for all the occurrence in a line I wanted to make stop at the first occurrence of the pattern and continue at the next line.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You want to replace only the first occurrence *per line*? What would be an example of the content and expected output?

Comment: Man Now what i do? In question: `i wanted to make stop at the first occurence` and In comment: `The problem is that it stops searching for all.` I want to ask you `You want but you do not want?`

Comment: Please post your input - so that we have a clear picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: The Basic High Speed HDMI 0.5m Cables with Ethernet are 0.5m suitable for use with HDMI.<br>
Home Theater, 1m Games Consoles (including Nintendo Wii U), 1m Blu-rays, Cable or Satelite 1m boxes and Projectors.  In the Above Example only the First 0.5m should be highlighted nothe second one
Simillarly for 1m

Comment: @AspiringAqib: Most likely, he wants to search the text with multiple regex, but continue on from previous regex instead of restarting all over.

Comment: @IvinPoloSony: Can you edit your question to include that input?

Comment: @IvinPoloSony what yes?

Comment: @AspiringAqib "Most likely, he wants to search the text with multiple regex, but continue on from previous regex instead of restarting all over". I am saying yes to that

Comment: Well, I think @IvinPoloSony you should consult that with Jack now. Because he has much knowledge than me. MaashAllah. I have deleted my answer so, I am free from this question.

Comment: @Jack i have edited the question with an example. The o/p will be a red highlight of the pattern Xm X.Xm etc

Comment: @IvinPoloSony I don't see the edit.

Comment: @IvinPoloSony And the expected output?

Comment: The o/p will be a red highlight of the pattern Xm X.Xm etc like 0.5m will be in red

Comment: @IvinPoloSony If my answer doesn't provide that output, leave a comment there, explaining why it's not correct.

Comment: @Jack ur code works for the specified string 1m 2m 3m\n2m 1m 5m", etc but they are not fixed i wanted something dynamic. Xm or X meter etc

Comment: @IvinPoloSony Your example string doesn't contain any "metre" or "meter". I've updated my answer for "X m" or "X metre".

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want:

```
var s = "1m 2m 3m\n2m 1m 5m",
re = /^.*?([\d.]+(?:m|metre))/gim;

console.log(s.replace(re, '<span class="red">$1</span>'));

"<span class="red">1m</span> 2m 3m
<span class="red">2m</span> 1m 5m"
```

It uses the `/m` modifier so that `^` has the meaning of "start of line" instead of just "start of subject". Then, it looks for the first thing that matches `<digits-or-dot>m` and performs the replacement.

If your content contains `<br>`, those would obviously not count as a newline, so you would need to replace those first:

```
s = s.replace('<br>', "<br>\n");
```

Comment: Line here seems to be defined by `<br>`

Comment: @nhahtdh Well, a simple `<br> -> \n` replacement should take care of that.

Comment: `<br>` is for HTML break-line and `\r\n` is Windows line-break.

Comment: I'd suggest using `s = s.replace(/<br>/g, "<br />\n");`, to keep the HTML newlines. (Regex is necessary to replace all occurrences.)

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the `g` after your regular expression?

Comment: Removing the g makes it stop but doesnt continue at the next line